# How can I create a menu item for terminal-applications starting in background mode

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, menu, elasticsearch

I want to start e.g. my ElasticSearch instance which is installed manually via one-click in the cinnamon menu.

What I can do is `/opt/elasticsearch-1.6.2/bin/elasticsearch &` and the application is starting in the background. So I want the same behaviour by adding a menu item. But I cannot start this in background mode, only foreground seems to work.

Working (but only fg):

```bsh
$ cat ~/.local/share/applications/elasticsearch-1.6.2.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.6.2
Type=Application
Name=ElasticSearch
Icon=/opt/elasticsearch-1.6.2/bin/elasticsearch-icon.png
Exec="/opt/elasticsearch-1.6.2/bin/elasticsearch"
Comment=ElasticSearch 1.6.2
Categories=Development;Server;
Terminal=true
StartupWMClass=elasticsearch
```

Not working (trying to set an `&` in Exec at the end):

```bsh
Exec="/opt/elasticsearch-1.6.2/bin/elasticsearch &"
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the most sufficient answer. But this worked for me, finally:

1. Create a shell script which start ElasticSearch via `nohup`

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env sh
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
   nohup /opt/elasticsearch-1.6.2/bin/elasticsearch 2> /dev/null &
   ```
2. Move the shell script to /usr/local/bin (optional) and make it executable

   ```
   chmod +x elasticsearch && mv elasticsearch /usr/local/bin/
   ```
3. Configure the desktop entry to call shell script

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.6.2
   Type=Application
   Name=ElasticSearch
   Icon=/opt/elasticsearch-1.6.2/bin/elasticsearch-icon.png
   Exec=elasticsearch
   Comment=ElasticSearch 1.6.2
   Categories=Development;Server;
   Terminal=false
   StartupWMClass=elasticsearch
   ```

This approach needs `nohup` as an additional resource, but has the advantage that the outsourcing to shell script is a more general solution, maybe also suitable for other applications.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e /opt/elasticsearch-1.6.2/bin/elasticsearch &
```

That should use the default terminal (you can specify your preferred one if compatible), which usually supports -e (xterm, ROXterm, XFCE4-terminal). It works for me with alsamixer.

Comment: I tried this without success. A terminal window is opened and command was given as expected. But the ElasticSearch instance was destroyed after closing terminal.

Comment: I didn't realise until I did a web-search what elastic search was. It appears to be a background process providing an API. Pretty sure there's a "correct calling convention" documented in the manual pages or site (something like /path/to/elasticsearch --daemonize) or a service provided for it. Still, glad you found a workable solution.